# OData model binding in XML with $expand

Tags: data-binding, odata, sapui5

I'm trying to bind data from the back end to XML view.

Here is my List control definition:

```js
<List items="{path : '/ZZMM_VDB_DETAILSet', parameters:{expand: 'ZZMM_VDB_DETAIL_TO_MATKLSSet'}}">
    <items>
        <CustomListItem>
            <content>
                <List items="{path: 'ZZMM_VDB_DETAIL_TO_MATKLSSet'}">
                    <items>
                        <ObjectListItem title="Matkl : {Matkl}"></ObjectListItem>
                    </items>
                </List>
            </content>
        </CustomListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

I want to display the data of the expanded entity set which consists of 16 objects.

What I get displayed is 15 times object before the last one (array element number 14) and the last row is the data of the last array element (number 15).

What do I miss here?

Comment: What is the cardinality between `ZZMM_VDB_DETAILSet` and `ZZMM_VDB_DETAIL_TO_MATKLSSet`?

Comment: @boghyon I'm looking at Associations, and it's as follows: Principal Entity Cardinality = 0, Dependent Entity Cardinality = M

Comment: I see. And which one is the Principal? `ZZMM_VDB_DETAIL` or `ZZMM_VDB_DETAIL_TO_MATKLS`?

Comment: @boghyon `ZZMM_VDB_DETAIL` is Principal. `ZZMM_VDB_DETAIL_TO_MATKLS` is navigation property to entity  named `ZZMM_VDB_MATKLS` (which is Dependent)

Comment: Just to make sure: if you navigate from one `ZZMM_VDB_DETAILSet` entity to the dependent `ZZMM_VDB_DETAIL_TO_MATKLSSet`, are you expanding to a collection or to a single entity?

Comment: @boghyon I navigate to a collection. Basically, every object in Principal array has a sub-array of Dependent entity under `ZZMM_VDB_DETAIL_TO_MATKLSSet` property.